# Query runs fine in phpMyAdmin, yet 0 results in php itself...?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Does anyone happen to know why this query when executed in phpMyAdmin gives me all the data I need.

But when executed programmatically in PHP, it returns 0 rows.

Thanks!

```
 SELECT `table_schema`, `table_name` 
     FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
     WHERE `Engine`='MyISAM' 
     AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` !='information_schema' 
     AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` !='mysql';
```

Update:

Here is the asked for PHP code.

```
$query = "SELECT `table_schema`, `table_name` 
    FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
    WHERE `Engine`='MyISAM' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` !='information_schema' AND `TABLE_SCHEMA` !='mysql'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo '--:'.mysql_num_rows($result).':--';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

And yes I'm using double quotes...

Comment: when executing in php, are you using double quotes around it, because you have single quotes inside

Comment: both apps use the same account or least have the same permissions?

Comment: both use root on localhost with no pass...

Comment: Do a `echo mysql_error();` right after you execute the query in PHP. Most likely you'll get a permission denied error.

Comment: well those do not look like single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serhiy,

I have also tried this sort of thing, and what I noticed is that phpmyadmin query strings are not exactly compatible with PHP query strings.  phpmyadmin, tends to add a few extra characters to its query strings.

In your PHP query try something like:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'information_schema' AND TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'mysql'
```

Good luck!

H

Comment: @Serhiy, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: ughhhh, yeah, i forgot that different db's use different symbols for the "is not" operator. sometimes != won't work and it's <> instead.

Comment: @Jerry Saravia, I hear you man, I work with Microsoft products at work during the day: ASP.net, C#, etc. then at night I work on my own projects using PHP, jQuery, MySQL, etc.  Switching between all these languages can get a bit confusing.  Especially when trying to debug!  You look at the code and think "that looks legit" only to find out you used syntax from a different language.

Answer (score 1):

We would need to see your PHP code to help you out and give you more definitive answers but from the look of that SQL query, you might be having issues with the backquotes and single quotes.

Try removing all the back quotes around the table_schema, table_name, information_schema, TABLES and all the back quotes really.

After that, use double quotes around the query string but leave the single quotes around the ...'information_schema..',...'mysql'...., and ...'MyISAM'....

Let us know how that goes and post your actual PHP code to get better help.

Comment: If that didn't work, you could try replacing the backticks with single quotes. I recall having a similiar problem once, but I forget how i solved it. Hope that helps